# Custom firebase Ids using Rest Api in C#

Tags: c#, .net, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, rest

I have a firebase real-time database as my app backend. I store profiles data in firebase,
See the below picture of how it stores my data using Rest Api in C# Xamarin.Forms

[image]

The problem is; I can't fetch one profile because I don't know the Id generated by firebase for the key of the profile.

I want something like that, that I can use my key instead of firebase generated keys.

[image]

I have searched over the internet for custom firebase Ids, I have found some solutions that were implemented using libraries and firebase SDKs. I am not using anyone of them, but I need the solution in Rest Apis.

Answer (score -1):

Greetings I know it's late but still I am positing this answer as it might be helpful to you on your next project or to someone else.
I had created a **[FireTime](https://github.com/Techzy-Programmer/FireTime)** library in c# consuming the Firebase realtime database REST API.
You might need to use the *[UpdateAsync](https://github.com/Techzy-Programmer/FireTime/blob/2d7ca5c089a975d13f00b7f69e942cdf7687a689/FireTime.Example/Update-Remove-Example.cs#L10)* feature as described in the documentation!

Let me know if you need any further support regarding this, I will be glad in assisting you.
Cheers.

Comment: I want to use REST Api.

Comment: Hi @NaveedHematmal I know what you are trying to achieve and you can even achieve that by using purely REST API as documented by the official [Firebase Documentation Here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/database). But please be aware that writing whole thing again from scratch is not recommended at all for big projects it's like **Re-Inventing** the wheel again. However please notice that all other Libraries are also using the REST API so you can simply go with it or create your very own if you don't want to use any third-party Library. **Happy Coding**!